# Objective-C - Understanding view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I understand that view controllers help control multiple views in an application, but I have trouble understanding when to use them.

If I have an application with a main page, several views with a "hierarchy" structure, and an about page not connected with the hierarchy, what files should my application have? An appdelegate, navigation controller and view controller? More than one view controller? Just a navigation controller?

Also, should they all be contained in one .xib file, or multiple .xib files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good habit is to have a `UIViewController` for each page you want to show. If I get the structure of your app you should have a main page (with many other `UIView`s inside it) and another page (about page). If that's true I suggest two `UIViewController`s.

The `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` that lets you "navigate" among the pages. It's not strictly necessary but suggested (you can also implement your self a custom navigation system, but it's easier to exploit the one Apple offers you). Another navigation system is the one based on [UITabBarController](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=HRVkTpnQH6KF4gTI3IidCg&usg=AFQjCNF7gC6Jr_ohH_O2rLDm8k8xPFR32A&sig2=q98PKFjdzqkc0mExypMEbg), if you want to take a look.

Assuming I get the structure of your app you should need two .xib file, one for each page you have.

The app delegate is conceptually different from a view controller, you'll have just a single app delegate, automatically created by Xcode (you can, of course, modify it to fit your needs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to help me visualise it, what do you think the project for the Contacts app on the iPhone would look like? Besides the app delegate, would it just be one view controller class (.m and .h) and one .xib file with multiple views (i.e. one view for the main list, then another view with details on the chosen person)?

Comment: Apparently there are a `UINavigationController` and three `UIViewController`s (with three .xib): in the main page there's the list of contacts, showed in a `UITableView`. Touching a contact you'll move to a secondary view where you can see contacts information. Another `UIViewController` is necessary for the page where you can add new contacts. Obviously it can have a different structure, but it can surely be a way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Each "screenful of content" (Apple uses this term) should be handled by it's `UIViewController` or more likely a subclass of it. The point of view controller is to handle view appearing or disappearing (going on/offscreen), device rotation, memory management, navigating to other view controllers and so on. If you are creating your UI with IB, then each of those view controllers would most likely have it's own .xib file.

Each view controller has one view (it's `view` property) that acts as main view for each "screenful of content" to which you then add your subviews.

`UINavigationController` and `UITabBarcontroller` are there to help you control the hierarchy of your app. They only act as containers for other view controllers and don't contain any UI except navigation bar or tab bar. Using tab bar controller you can have multiple view controllers which act exactly like browser tabs. Using navigation controller you can have a stack-like navigation where new view controllers are pushed from right to left and are popped from left to right when user goes back to previous view controller. You can even have a view controller inside navigation controller inside a tab bar controller.

If you don't want to use tab bar or navigation controller, you can navigate through your view controllers by presenting them modally using `presentModalViewController:animated:` and dismissing by `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`. If you send `YES` for animated parameter of these methods, you will get an animation specified by the `modalTransitionStyle` property of view controller being presented or dismissed. Possible animations are slide in from bottom (default), horizontal flip of entire screen, fade in/out and half-page curl.

There are also some Apple-provided subclasses of UIViewController that help you setup your UI quicker like `UITableViewController` which is basically a view controller that contains a table as it's main view and conforms to 'UITableViewdataSource`and`delegate` protocols which are required to define how each cell looks and what it contains.

On iPad there is one additional container controller `UISplitViewController` and  one additional way to present new view controllers using `UIPopover`.